# Menu Tab is not working properly using Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to Framework, I'm facing problem while refreshing the page, the color of the tab, by default it is showing first tab, but i want the tab color to change only when i click on the particular Menu of the tab. Even after refreshing also whatever the page is open then it should should that respective tab only, It should not show the first tab by default. Can anyone help me in this query?

Here is the Code:

```
 <div className={classes.root}>
        <Drawer
          className={classes.drawer}
          variant="permanent"
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper
          }}
        >
          <div className={classes.toolbar} />
          <List>
            {["table", "text"].map((item, index) => {
              const Icon = itemsConfig[item].icon;
              return (
                <ListItem
                  component={Link}
                  to={itemsConfig[item].link}
                  selected={index === this.state.selectedIndex}
                  onClick={event => this.handleListItemClick(event, index)}
                  button
                  key={item}
                >
                  <ListItemIcon>
                    <Icon />
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={itemsConfig[item].text} />
                </ListItem>
              );
            })}
          </List>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
```

Comment: If you don't want to lose the state of your app even after reload then you should store that in `localStorage` and retrieve it when you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `localStorage` because you don't want to lose your `selectedIndex`'s value even after a page reload.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: parseInt(localStorage.getItem('selectedIndex'), 10) || 0
    };
  }

  handleListItemClick = (event, index) => {
    localStorage.setItem('selectedIndex', index);
    this.setState({
      selectedIndex: index
    });
  };
```

**update**

You can use `-1` as the value for `selectedIndex` as -1 doesn't relate to any element in `["table", "text"]`. This will make sure that by default none of the tabs are selected.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: -1
    };
  }
```

**update 2**

You can use `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook and change `selectedIndex` accordingly:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: -1
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    switch (this.props.location.pathname) {
      case "/Table":
        this.setState({ selectedIndex: 0 });
        break;
      case "/Text":
        this.setState({ selectedIndex: 1 });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: By default it is showing `Table` tab and moreover if i go to `Text` Tab and when i refresh the page without /text then also it is showing the Text Tab. Is it possible to not to show any color when it is in the home page "/"

Comment: @Arunya You can give it an initial value like `-1`. see my updated answer

Comment: @Arunya If you are depending on the localStorage for selecting the tabs then the route `/text` doesn't matter because `selectedIndex` will be based on the value stored in localStorage.

Comment: If i give -1, then same thing is happening, I mean it is not showing color but when i refresh the page in `/table` tab then also it is not showing color for Table Tab.

Comment: Updated my answer.